# Laravel 4 pagination count

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have set a pagination in my specific view/site, and it works.

The problem is I have a php counter:

```
<?php $count = 0;?> 
   @foreach ($players as $player)
    <?php $count++;?>
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $count }}. </td>
```

and whenever I switch pages, it starts from 1.

How could I change that?

Answer (score 17):

In order to achieve that, you need to initialize the value of counter:

```
<?php $count = (($current_page_number - 1) * $items_per_page) + 1; ?>
```

**Notice** I'm first subtracting `1` from current page, so the first page number is `0`. Then I'm adding `1` to the total result, so your first item starts with `1`, instead of `0`.

Laravel Paginator provides a handy shortcut for that:

```
<?php $count = $players->getFrom() + 1; ?>
@foreach ($players as $player)
    ...
```

There are a few others that you can use as you like:

```
$players->getCurrentPage();
$players->getLastPage();
$players->getPerPage();
$players->getTotal();
$players->getFrom();
$players->getTo();
```

Comment: I've tried implementing it, but can't find a way, the 3 is not in the # table row. Could you put it in the view? paste.laravel.com/J99

Comment: You need to change line 19 of your paste to `<?php $count = $players->getFrom() + 1; ?>`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Didn't know those methods existed, this should be marked as the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately `getFrom` and `getTo` are no longer available in Laravel 5

Comment: @andrewtweber - They are replaced by `$paginator->firstItem()` and `$paginator->lastItem()` as you can read here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade

Comment: @Musterknabe I missed that, thanks! I didn't know `getFrom` existed until I found this question, so I never knew to upgrade it either :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo "Displaying ".$data->getFrom() ." - ".$data->getTo(). " of ".number_format($data->getTotal())." result(s)"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

We only need method `getFrom` from Paginator instance to be able counting from the first item in the page.

```
<?php $count = $players->getFrom(); ?> 
@foreach ($players as $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $count++ }}. </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $count++; ?>
@if($players->getCurrentPage() > 1)
{{ ((($players->getCurrentPage() - 1)* $players->getPerPage()) + $count)}}
@else
{{$count}}
@endif
```

Comment: I've tried implementing it, but can't find a way, the 3 is not in the # table row. Could you put it in the view? http://paste.laravel.com/J99

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a counter.

After you get the key that starts from 0, you need to add 1.
After that you add the current page-1 * items per page

You can do it like this:

```
@foreach ($players as $key => $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $key+1+(($players->getCurrentPage()-1)*$players->getPerPage()) }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and elegant:

```
@foreach ($players as $key => $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $players->getFrom() + $key }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```