# Laravel 5.1 pagination count

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.1

I am using the paginator of Laravel to display 100 results per page. In the front of each row I'm currently displaying the ID of the database field. However, I want to display the count.

[I've found some threads on stackoverflow solving this issue for Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213089/laravel-4-pagination-count)

Where they say, you should solve it like this

```
<?php $count = $players->getFrom(); ?> 
@foreach ($players as $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $count++ }}. </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

or like this

```
<?php $count = $players->getFrom() + 1; ?>
@foreach ($players as $player)
    ...
```

The problem here, is that Laravel 5.1 doesn't have the `getForm` method anymore. The [upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade) says to replace `getFrom` by `firstItem`, which I did. Unfortunetely, I'm not getting the correct numbers.

I tried it like this

```
<?php $count = $pages->firstItem() + 1 ?>
@foreach ($pages as $page)
    @include('pages.singlepagebasic')
@endforeach
```

and like this

```
{{ $count = $pages->firstItem() }}
@foreach ($pages as $page)
    @include('pages.singlepagebasic')
@endforeach
```

//pages.singlebasic.blade.php

```
{{ $count ++ }}
```

but my site always displays only the number "2" instead of counting up. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Just use this to get pages count

```
$players->lastPage()
```

or this to get items count

```
$players->total()
```

If you want every entry count DONT DO {{ $count++ }} because its echoing data. Instead do like that

```
<?php $count++; ?>
{{ $count }}
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want the current number of the entry. Let's say I have 100 items. Then I want to do a foreach over those items and display the current number next to it. So 1,2,3,4,5, etc.

Comment: I edited my question. Problem is that you're trying to ECHO $count++, thats what {{ }} do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all get 100 players with `paginate(100)` method then you can get the index or count in the following way:

```
<?php $count = 1; ?> 
@foreach ($players as $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$players ->perPage()*($players->currentPage()-1)+$count}}</td>
    </tr>
<?php $count++; ?>
    @endforeach
```

Here `{{$players ->perPage()*($players->currentPage()-1)+$count}}` will print the index or count like 1 to 100 on first page and 101 to 200 on next page and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use laravel 5 loop itration

```
`@foreach ($players as $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$players->perPage()*($players->currentPage()-1)+$loop->iteration}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach`
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What i used to do in order to avoid php tags in blade templates in 4.2 was something like that

```
@foreach ($players as $key => $player)
<tr>
    <td>{{ (Input::get('page', 1) - 1) * $players->getPerPage() + $key + 1 }}. </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

It's kinda strange but it will do the trick.