# Laravel - Use $loop->iteration with pagination

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make something similar to reddit (just the ranking idea in a list of rows) and want each row counted consecutively.

Example [image: Reddit listing]

I can do this on one page with the tag

```
{{ $loop->iteration }}
```

Unfortunately, when I go to the second page, as I am using pagination, the numbers start over at 1. However, I would like them to continue from the last number on the previous page.

Any idea how to fix this?

I appreciate your help! :)

Comment: Can't you just do e.g. `{{ $loop->iteration + $perPage * ($currentPage - 1) }}` or similar?

Comment: Thanks @Joel Hinz. I liked your idea. It didn't give me the right answer straight away, but did give me an idea. Upon further searching, I found a similar question. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247499/laravel-5-1-pagination-count

Comment: Sorry guys for the duplicate question!

Answer (score 17):

you can use $loop->index instead of $loop->iteration in the following way

```
{{ ($players ->currentpage()-1) * $players ->perpage() + $loop->index + 1 }}
```

Answer (score 3):

for inverse count with pagination

```
{{ ($players->total()-$loop->index)-(($players->currentpage()-1) * $players->perpage() ) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way : (change $users to your collection name)

```
{{ $loop->iteration + $users->firstItem() - 1 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use this method in paginator the first index can be retrieved from the ->firstItem(). Like

```
@foreach($homeworks as $homework)
<tr>
<td>{{ $homeworks->firstItem() + $loop->index }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
{{ $products->firstItem()+$loop->index }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the duplicate question and big thanks to @JoelHinz for the idea. Upon further searching, I found the correct answer.

[Laravel 5.1 pagination count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247499/laravel-5-1-pagination-count)

```
<?php $count = 1; ?> 
@foreach ($players as $player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$players ->perPage()*($players->currentPage()-1)+$count}}</td>
    </tr>
    <?php $count++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

use **firstItem()** method in loop :

```
    @foreach($contents as $index=>$record  )
       <tr>
           <th scope="row">{!!  $contents->firstItem() +$index!!}</th>
       </tr>
   @endforeach
```