# Start retrieved records at 0 MySQL Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a forum I'm building and replies are always incrementing with their unique id's.

This means that I can have a thread and have the reply number at 550 when the thread starts, not displaying the correct reply number in relation to the thread.

Is there anyway that when I retrieve these records, I can reset them to 1 and have them increment respective to their threads?

Thanks for any help.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@for($i = 0; $i < $thread->replies->count(); $i++)
      Post {{ $i }} of {{ $thread->replies->count() }}
@endfor
```

It seems to work except this is stuck in my $replies as $reply loop and it proliferates all records.

Comment: do you want to show us the minimum amount of code that can show your problem? so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `@foreach` loop and the `$loop` variable to do the counting, [See the `$loop` doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#the-loop-variable)

```
@foreach($thread->replies as $post)
      Post {{ $loop->iteration }} of {{ $loop->count }}
@endfor
```

In the case of spanning multiple pages, you should implement Pagination instead [See the Pagination doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#introduction)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did this and it worked. However there's another problem that the it actually spans across several pages as I paginate it for reach 10 replies, so it counts 1-10 for each page instead of the whole.

Comment: Looks like a perfect use case for pagination - see updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ ($replies->currentPage()-1) * $replies->perPage() + $loop->index + 1 }} of {{ $replies->total() }}
```

Found here: [Laravel - Use $loop->iteration with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400398/laravel-use-loop-iteration-with-pagination/50830535)